# Помогите с запросом (максимальное соответствие)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом.
Существуют таблица с данными:

```
ID | CODE
1  |1
2  |112
3  |1113
4  |11114
```

Как построить запрос так, что бы я мог выбрать запись с максимальным количеством совпадений символов в начале строки.

Допустим, в условии выборки передаем 11114980349, такому условию наиболее соответсвует запись 11114. СУБД PostgreSQL. Возможно ли построить запрос без полнотекстового поиска?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе можно конечно, но вот нужно ли ... По крайней мере подобные запросы точно не смогут использовать индексы и будут работать полным перебором таблицы. Возможно стоило бы поискать другие пути ...

```
select code from Table
 order by length(array_to_string(regexp_matches(code, '^11?1?1?4?9?8?0?3?4?9?'),'')) desc
 limit 1;
```

Приходится задействовать регулярные выражения и расставить знаки `?` после каждого символа выражения, начиная со второго. `regexp_matches` возвращает массив всех совпадений, в нашем случае оно может быть только одно, так как мы ограничились началом строки (поставили `^`), причем будет выдана максимальная совпавшая часть строки. Остается отсортировать по количеству совпавших символов по убыванию и взять одну строку.

Answer (score 2):

Так?

```
select max(code) from T
where '11114980349' like code || '%'
```

Comment: Автор вопроса привел еще и примеры типа 1113, я так понял, что они считаются соответствующими, но менее. т.е. после искомого куска строки может быть еще что то. И тогда ваш лайк не сработает ...

Comment: Mike, сработает всегда мой Like. 
Стихи. :-)

Comment: Мне показалось по условию задачи, что 1111400 так же подходящий кандидат. А '11114980349' like '1111400%' не сработает

Comment: Mike, вы поняли задачу так, а я иначе. Без автора спорить не о чем.